# Is it safe to use a DbContext which in turns uses HttpContext in a Blazor Server app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

We use this for multi-tenancy stuff. The DbContext generates the connection string based on the request's host.

We are considering to use Blazor Server Side for some new features but we are worried about the fact that because the HttpContext is unreliable inside of a Razor Component's scope, the functioning of our DbContext may be affected too when it is instanciated from the Razor component.

I haven't found any documentation that describes this scenario.

In case the HttpContext does not work properly inside the DbContext, data about customers could be leaked to other customers. This is our main concern.

Comment: It's not easy to get the HttpContext in a Blazor Server side app, Like having the HttpContext on a SignalR connection.

Comment: What HttpContext issue?

Comment: The fact that is is unreliable inside a Razor component's scope.

Comment: I must say I've had no luck with Blazor on getting the current user/client. I tried grabbing it at the beginning and store it in a class instance, but gets wiped out inside new scopes (like OwningComponent - something you should really do with DbContext if possible).